# How do i send a response to the front end whether or not the if statement is true

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

How do i send a response to the front end whether or not the if statement is true
i tried to use res.status() but when i look at the response it has not changed
im recieving this response from the front end
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/register?
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 OK
even though im trying to get a response from the backend with either res.status(200)
or res.status(400)

```
const UserModel = require("./Server/models/User")
const Post = require("./Server/models/Post")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/BlogSite")




    



app.use(express.json())

app.get("/",(req,res)=> {
    res.send("Home")
})




app.post("/api/register",(req,res)=> {
  
    console.log(req.body)
    const username =(req.body.username)
    const password = (req.body.password)
 
    UserModel.create({username:username,password:password},(err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        else{
            console.log("User Created")
            res.status(200).send("Home");
        }
    })
    

    
    
    
});

app.post("/api/login",(req,res)=> {
UserModel.find({username: req.body.username,password :req.body.password},(err,data) =>{
    

    if (data.length == 1){
        console.log("Logged in")
       app.post("/api/restatus",(req,res)=>{
           console.log("sent")
       })
    }
    else{
        console.log("Wrong Email or password")
        res.status(401)
    }
})
})



app.listen(3001,()=> {
    console.log("listening on port 3001")
})
```

Frontend

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Register() {
const [username,setUsername] = useState("")
const [password,setPassword] = useState("")


function handleSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault
fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/register",{
  method:"post",
  headers:{
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
  },
  body:JSON.stringify({username:username,password:password})
})
.then(function(res){ console.log(res) })
.catch(function(res){ console.log(res) })


} 



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <input placeholder="username" value={username} onChange={ e => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
        <input placeholder="password " value={password} onChange={ e => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
        <button  type='submit' >Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Register;
```

Answer (score 0):

please use async/await for more cleaner code, try this:

```
const UserModel = require("./Server/models/User")
const Post = require("./Server/models/Post")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/BlogSite")
app.use(express.json())

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Home")
})

app.post("/api/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body)
    const username = (req.body.username)
    const password = (req.body.password)
    await UserModel.create({ username: username, password: password })
    res.status(200).send("Home");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
});

app.post("/api/login", async (req, res) => {
  const data = await UserModel.find({ username: req.body.username, password: req.body.password })
  if (data.length == 1) {
    console.log("Logged in")
    res.status(200).send("Logged in");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Wrong Email or password")
    res.status(401).send("Wrong Email or password");
  }
})



app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 3001")
})
```